# How to move obj's uv map to another obj?(same shape but different vertices)

Tags: uv

I have two obj with Almost the same shape but different vertices/faces. I wonder how can I move uv coords/map from one obj to another?

Comment: Bake from selected to active. Search for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the vertex count is exactly the same as the source object, otherwise the transfer wont be possible, each vertex has an index number, the operator uses that to know how the data should be preserved.

[image]

2. While in object mode, Select the object you want the UVs transferred first, then while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select the source object with the original UVs,
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the *Link/Transfer data* popup > Select *Copy UV maps*

[image]

[image]

The final object shall now have the same UV layout successfully transferred.